# Username and Email Regex with very specific rules

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to make a single regex to validate usernames. So far I have:

```
/^[^\.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*[^\.]{1}$/
```

but it is not working as I expected.

The following rules are used to validate usernames:

1. It must be greater then 3 character long. (`minlength = 3`)
2. It must be less then 20 characters long. (`maxlength = 20`)
3. It may contain at most one period.

   - E.g. <kbd>xyz</kbd> and <kbd>xyz.com</kbd> are valid but <kbd>xyz.abc.com</kbd> is invalid.
4. It must not contain a period at the start or end of the string.

   - E.g. <kbd>.xyz</kbd> or <kbd>xyz.</kbd> are invalid).
5. Aside from the optional period, it may contain only `[A-Za-z0-9]` characters.

Additionally, on another page, users are permitted to enter either their username or email address. Is there any way to validate that a string is *either* a valid username or a valid email address in the same regular expression?

Some examples of valid values:

1. <kbd>abc</kbd>
2. <kbd>abc.com</kbd>
3. <kbd>abc@zyx.com</kbd> (email address)
4. <kbd>abc123</kbd>
5. <kbd>123abc</kbd>
6. <kbd>1a2b3c</kbd>

Some examples of invalid values:

1. <kbd>.abc</kbd>    (leading period)
2. <kbd>abc.</kbd>    (trailing period)
3. <kbd>a b c</kbd>   (invalid characters)
4. <kbd>abc@xyz</kbd> (invalid email address)
5. <kbd>a.b.c</kbd>   (multiple periods)
6. <kbd>a-b$c</kbd>   (invalid characters)

Comment: `abc@xyz` is a perfectly valid email address. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 3):

it's very easy if you check the length in a script instead of using regexp

but you can do this using look-ahead if you must:

```
/^(?=[a-z0-9.]{3,20}$)[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

<s>`[A-Za-z0-9]` is the same as `\w`</s>

if you want to use the same regexp to validate `username` OR `e-mail` address, just put your second regexp after `|` sign like:

```
/^(?=[a-z0-9.]{3,20}$)[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$|^.*@\w+\.[\w.]+$/i
```

`^.*@\w+\.[\w.]+$` is a very simple mail validation in this case (you may want to use better one)

You shouldn't do too much in a single regexp.

Comment: oh, you're right. Allowing `_` sign along with alphanumerical is so common that I forgot about it. Just replace `\w` with `[A-Za-z0-9]` then

Comment: But it DOESN'T depend on locale (at least not in javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I made a solution for it for username it only allows underscore as special character in username and also helps to validate email at the same time

`/^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$|^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i`